# Django objects.filter() with multiple choice checkbox

Tags: django, django-models

I have a MultiSelectField (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield) and I'm trying to implement some basic search into my app. I want the filter to return a result when one of the checkboxes matches the query.

e.g.

1. Option A
2. Option B

Assuming both Option A and Option B are present (i.e., in the db, there's A, B), selecting either one of them (A or B) should return the row. `__in` doesn't seem to work in my case. How should I implement this?

edit: Some code:

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('1', ‘a'),
        ('2', ‘b'),
        ('3', ‘c'),
    )

    foo = MultiSelectField(choices=CHOICES)
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            foo = request.POST.getlist('foo')
            profiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(foo=foo)
```

I tried `UserProfile.objects.filter(foo__in=foo)` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You heed to show us some more code.

Comment: Please show your entire model and your entire view.

Comment: Added my models and views.